# Regex replace one named group based on another

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Given the following regex and two lines of input:

```
replace (?<target>.*), but not (?<source>.*),
```

> Keeping the line intact, replace me, but not you, keep this too.
>
> Retaining me, replace one, but not two, ignore three.

[image]

I want to replace the text with new 'target' values, calculated from the value in 'source'.  Leaving the rest of the document unchanged.

The new 'target' is a complex calculation, and must be calculated in pure C#.

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you copy/paste input and regex please?

Comment: And best is show your code. You can always capture submatches, and then make use of the match evaluator.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The calculation (what I assume you're asking for by 'code') isn't important, I'm looking for a general solution to this kind of problem.  My actual scenario is too 'noisy' to ask as a question.

Comment: Could you just simplify it? What is the expected result for the above string?

Comment: Why not using [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) using a `MatchEvaluator`. You match your whole regex and return `"replace " + <much complex calc> + ", but not " + match.Groups["source"].Value + ","`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can just use a Match evaluator:

```
var line = "Keeping the line intact, replace me, but not you, keep this too.\n\nRetaining me, replace one, but not two, ignore three.";
var res = Regex.Replace(line, @"replace (?<target>.*), but not (?<source>.*),",
          m => "replace " + m.Groups["source"].Value.Replace("o", "1") + ", but not " + m.Groups["source"].Value + ",");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/tGkS0X)

I just replaced all `o` with `1` in the first capture group for demo. Note that in this scenario, there is not point capturing the target group, you can just keep it as a non-capturing group, or as no group at all.